# Gradient descent with non-Lipschitz continuous gradients

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

In general, we know that for strongly convex functions for which we can compute the Hessian and find the Lipschitz constant $L$ of the gradient, gradient descent will converge provided that the step size $\alpha < 1/L$. This, for example, would trivially hold for gradient descent on $f(x) = x^2$; it is on every textbook in numerical methods. For this class of functions I could also compute the Hessian and run a second-order method (Newton or quasi-Newton depending on the Hessian approximation or computation).

However, let $f(x) = (x^2)_+$ (clipping the square loss for negative values). Then the first derivative is not differentiable anymore (discontinuity in $0$) and $f$ is not twice continuously differentiable. Still, while second order methods cannot be applied, I can run gradient descent.

How would one then choose the step size for gradient descent in this case, since the Hessian is not defined? In my specific case above, I can bound the gradient with a constant, and I can take the derivatives on both sides ignoring the discontinuity. But I cannot show it is Lipschitz-continuous. What are known results in this case?

Note: the true problem I am trying to solve is to run gradient descent on the Huber loss with appropriately chosen step size, but the root question is the same: how do we determine an acceptable step size for a function that is not twice differentiable everywhere, but has bounded gradient? Are there any special conditions that apply to find the step size for "well behaved" functions, even just in the univariate case?

Comment: Try a variable step size. The Armijo step size rule is a standard that is easy to analyse.

Comment: Note that in the particular example you have, the step size that works for $x \mapsto x^2 $ will work as either the iterates are all $\ge 0$ or not. If they are, it works the same as $x \mapsto x^2$,  if not it terminates as soon as it hits some $x<0$.

Comment: Indeed, I can implement Armijo or other step size searches, but my question was more on whether I could say something about the step size, given that the second derivative is defined almost everywhere, except at the discontinuity in $x=0$, that is, given I can bound the gradient. As I mentioned, my actual objective was having step size choice guidelines for the Huber loss, which is also not twice continuously differentiable, but whose gradient is easily bounded.

Comment: In your example, the gradient *is* Lipschitz continuous. You don't need the second derivative for that.

Comment: @AlexShtof is it? The function is $(x^2)_+$. Its first derivative is $(2 x)_+$, which is not continuously differentiable because there is a discontinuity at $x = 0$. The definition of a function being $L$-smooth is that $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L \|x - y\|$. This means in this case that  $2 |(x)_+ -  (y)_+| \leq L |x - y|$, which has then 4 cases to evaluate... ok, indeed you may be right about this one.

Comment: @V.C. another equivalent way you might consider is based on the result that a convex function $f$ is $L$-smooth if and only if the function $\phi_L(x) = \frac{L}{2} \|x\|_2^2 - f(x)$ is convex (the proof is easy - the gradient inequality applied to $\Phi_L$).
It's easy to see that $x^2 - (x)_+^2 = (-x)_+^2$ is convex, so your function is $L$-smooth with $L=2$.